# Is Intellij watchpoint condition evaluated before or after field modification

Tags: java, intellij-idea, watchpoint

In Intellij Java, when I create a field watchpoint and add a condition expression, is expression evaluated before or after field was mutated? If the field is evaluated in condition expression, result will be different in those 2 cases.